# Making a small application with the CiviCRM API

Tags: ajax

I'm currently trying to make a small web application in Cordova with which I can load memberships from my CiviCRM installation and display them. I already have access to my server url, the path, my personal key and the api_key, however the documentation is so unclear that I do not know how to proceed further.

I'd be delighted if someone could give me some example code on how I can interact further with my CiviCRM installation using Ajax.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is either https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v4/usage/#ajax, or the rest api at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v3/rest/

Api explorer, found at https://your.site/civicrm/api or /civicrm/api4, is useful for exploring the entities and actions available.

Answer (score 2):

You could review this Cordova based mobile app which integrates with CiviCRM, https://github.com/agileware/au.com.agileware.civicontact